# Trying to load multiple tables on a single page using VIEWSTATE in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have got this method to work for single pages on a project that I am working on. The problem is that when there are multiple tables that need to be changed dynamically, the logic becomes very complex.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class Part_9 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private const string VIEWSTATEKEY1 = "ContactCount";
    private const string VIEWSTATEKEY2 = "ContactCount";
    private const string VIEWSTATEKEY3 = "ContactCount";
    private const string VIEWSTATEKEY4 = "ContactCount";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Set the number of default controls
            ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY1] = ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY1] == null ? 1 : ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY1];
            ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY2] = ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY2] == null ? 1 : ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY2];
            ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY3] = ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY3] == null ? 1 : ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY3];
            ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY4] = ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY4] == null ? 1 : ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY4];

            //Load the contact control based on Vewstate key
            LoadPageControls1();
            LoadPageControls2();
            LoadPageControls3();
            LoadPageControls4();
        }
    }

    private void LoadPageControls1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY1].ToString()); i++)
        {
            Part9Table1.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControlPart9Table1.ascx"));
        }

        Part9Table2.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControlPart9Table2.ascx"));
        Part9Table3.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControlPart9Table3.ascx"));
        Part9Table4.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControlPart9Table4.ascx"));
    }

    private void LoadPageControls2()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY2].ToString()); i++)
        {
            Part9Table2.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControlPart9Table2.ascx"));
        }

        Part9Table1.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControlPart9Table1.ascx"));
        Part9Table3.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControlPart9Table3.ascx"));
        Part9Table4.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControlPart9Table4.ascx"));
    }

    private void LoadPageControls3()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY3].ToString()); i++)
        {
            Part9Table3.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControlPart9Table3.ascx"));
        }

        Part9Table1.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControlPart9Table1.ascx"));
        Part9Table2.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControlPart9Table2.ascx"));
        Part9Table4.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControlPart9Table4.ascx"));
    }

    private void LoadPageControls4()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY4].ToString()); i++)
        {
            Part9Table4.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControlPart9Table4.ascx"));
        }

        Part9Table1.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControlPart9Table1.ascx"));
        Part9Table2.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControlPart9Table2.ascx"));
        Part9Table3.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UserControlPart9Table3.ascx"));
    }

    protected void Unnamed2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Part 10.aspx");
    }

    protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Part 8.aspx");
    }

    protected void Unnamed3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY1] = int.Parse(ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY1].ToString()) + 1;
        LoadPageControls1();
    }

    protected void Unnamed4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY2] = int.Parse(ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY2].ToString()) + 1;
        LoadPageControls2();
    }

    protected void Unnamed5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY3] = int.Parse(ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY3].ToString()) + 1;
        LoadPageControls3();
    }

    protected void Unnamed6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY4] = int.Parse(ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY4].ToString()) + 1;
        LoadPageControls4();
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see here. when the page loads up the content, it will load 4 new rows in each table because there are 4 load content methods. But when I click on one of the buttons, it will correct itself and add the extra row that you want to the table you selected and resetting the rest of the tables to one row. However, if I then click on another button, it will add a row to it, plus the previous rows added and reset all the other tables to one which means that there is a variable counting the number of rows for each table collectively instead of individually.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your key for each viewstate is set to "ContactCount". You need to have unique identifiers for each one or else you are adding to all of them at once.

Unless I'm misunderstanding something :o

Comment: @SamMan Hi and welcome on Stackoverflow. To indicate that your problem is solved, pleas post your answer as Answer below, and accept it a such.

Comment: thanks man, I just realised that not long after i submitted the question. it works fine now that i made the changes above. Have only started using C# and ASP so still not the best at it :P.

Comment: Ok Marcel, it says that i have to wait 8 hours before I can answer my own question. Thanks for the welcome and the advice :)

Comment: We all had to start somewhere :)

On a side note, I personally like using viewstate contained within get/set properties. I find it is a lot cleaner as you don't have to write `Viewstate['blah']` constantly. Like this for example:
`private int ContactCount
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["ContactCount"] != null)
                    return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["ContactCount"]);
                else
                    return 1;
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["ContactCount"] = value;
            }
        }`

Comment: That will look a lot better. Think I'll add that when I'm cleaning up my code at the end of the project. Thanks very much for the advice man :)